# “A person who is burning inside in love”

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request, compound-nouns

Diljale is a person who was dumped by his love is not getting out of that madness and shock and is still burning inside called “Diljala.” in Hindi and Persian.

Dil heart and Jale the burnt one. Diljale is one word, but here according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diljale), it means “**the burning-heart**” I disagree with it. I want a single or made up of two words that describes a person who is burning inside in someone’s love.

Comment: Perhaps "consumed by love"? https://www.powerthesaurus.org/consumed_by_love/synonyms

Comment: @myacorn, is it a noun?

Comment: @JayHo It's good to remember that you are writing English, and not Hindi. It might be that an English speaker would express this idea by an adjective, or even a verb and not a noun.  If you start saying "I want the same part of speech as Hindi" you start writing sentences that are grammatically correct, but sound like they are not by a native speaker; you start writing "translationese" and not English.

Comment: There's 'jilted' but it's perhaps not close enough to be a direct replacement.